# Why does my shader index 0 when I try to index more than 1 << 26?

Tags: shader, vulkan

I have a strange occurrence where I have an array of indices which read from a storage buffer, and if I index into that buffer with 1 << 26 the data that's read appears to be junk, as my cube's translation doesn't show up on screen. However when I index with 1 << 27 I get the cube on the screen, meaning that it seemed to read from index 0. This seems really strange and I can't figure out why this is happening.

As an explanation for this, is there a mechanism that stops the program in the shader from indexing outside buffer range for memory access safety, and simply indexes at 0, which it possibly deduced is within range of the buffer bound, as the buffer range is specified when you bind it.

Comment: What exactly is the data you're reading? Assuming it was float4x4, then `2**26 * 2**2 * 2**4` (your index, multiplied by the float size, multiplied by the matrix element count) is at a raw memory offset of 2**32. I would not be super surprised if the shader isn't able to directly address more than a 32 bit memory offset.

Comment: @vandench So it then indexes 0? I was getting the correct data for the first element.

Comment: My naïve assumption would be that most implementations would behave the same as an integer overflow on the hardware type bitwidth, but if you are exceeding device limits you're in the realms of implementation-defined behavior at this point so "anything can happen".

Comment: Creating the device with `robustBufferAccess` enabled can add bounds clamping, but it's an opt-in feature.